# Flutter - Unclickable Button inside a TabBarView inside a Stack

Tags: flutter, button, stack, tabbar

I'm trying to create a button sticked under the `TabBar` and the right side of the screen. I placed it in a `TabBarView` inside a `Stack`, since it's what I need. But whatever I do, Flutter prioritizes the scrolling movements instead of the button click, which makes the button unclickable. You can still drag the screen even on the button. How can we fix this? I need both `TabBarView` and the button sticked to that specific place.

Using `GestureDetector` or `ElevatedButton` instead of `InkWell` or wrapping any of them with `AbsorbPointer` are not working.

I'm using Flutter version `sdk: ">=2.10.0 <3.0.0"`

[image: Design example]

Here's the full code for the gif above:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Test',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const Test(),
    );
  }
}

class Test extends StatefulWidget {
  const Test({Key key,}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Test> createState() => _TestState();
}

class _TestState extends State<Test> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin{
  TabController _tabController;

  @override
  void initState()
  {
    super.initState();
    _tabController = TabController(
      initialIndex: 0,
      length: 2,
      vsync: this,
    );
    _tabController.addListener(_handleTabIndex);
  }
  @override
  void dispose() {
    _tabController.removeListener(_handleTabIndex);
    _tabController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
  void _handleTabIndex() {
    setState(() {});
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        bottom: PreferredSize(
            preferredSize: const Size(250,40),
            child: Stack(
              children: [
                TabBar(
                  controller: _tabController,
                  onTap: (page) {},
                  tabs: const [
                    Text("tab1"),
                    Text("tab2")
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
      ),
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.topRight,
            child: InkWell(
              onTap: ()
              {
                print("boo");
              },
              child: Container(
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                width: 55,
                height: 31,
                decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.red,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(bottomLeft: Radius.circular(8)),
                ),
                child: const Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 4),
                  child: Text(
                    "Button",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 11.5,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          TabBarView(
            controller: _tabController,
            children: const [
              Center(child: Text("asdf")),
              Center(child: Text("ghjk"))
            ],
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because the button is behind the `TabBarView` in the stack so it doesn't receive the tap gesture, the `TabBarView` does.

Try Replacing the `InkWell` with `GestureDetector` and setting the `behavior` property of the `GestureDetector` to `HitTestBehavior.translucent`

This will make the button receive the tap as well as the `TabBarView`
Here are the docs of `translucent`

> Translucent targets both receive events within their bounds and permit
> targets visually behind them to also receive events.

Now, both should receive the tap gesture.

Comment: This was one of the solutions to a similar problem in stackoverflow, but this isn't working for me.

Comment: nope it didn't work..any another suggestions?